# How do make a 2D interpolation in a table in Python?

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a table of numbers, with two initial row and columns ( in Bold) which are values of CI and CII as input. my input can be a value between the values of these two, and based on that I should interpolate from the values of the table by crossing them.

so let's say , I should find the corresponding value from the table for CI = 0.33 which is between 0.3 and 0.35 on the Bolded first row and CII = 1.1.

Other questions on 2D interpolation did not really help me on this. **Because** I am using python add in in another software where I can not import **scipty.interp2D.**
I would be very thankfull if some solution would be suggested without the need to a specific library

[image: values]

I am not sure about the type of the interpolation to use. maybe linear. to give a better perspective, I plotted 3 arbitrary rows from the table, just taking the row and plotted against the sample number, it seems they have different behaviors over the samples. first ones increase, last ones are decreasing but never are a line :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of interpolation do you want? Polynomial? Exponentially piece-wise smooth? Is step-wise linear ok?

Assuming step-wise linear, you could just write up a function manually:

```
# Sample data. 
X    = [0,5,10] # Left to right, like in your table. 
Y    = [0,2]    # Top to bottom, like in your table. 
grid = [[1,2,4],[4,5,10]]

def f(x,y):
    # Find the vales that x and y are between. 
    xi,yi = None,None
    for i,(x1,x2) in enumerate(zip(X[:-1],X[1:])):
        if x1 <= x <= x2:
            xi,w_x2,w_x1 = i,(x-x1)/(x2-x1),(x2-x)/(x2-x1)
            break
    for i,(y1,y2) in enumerate(zip(Y[:-1],Y[1:])):
        if y1 <= y <= y2:
            yi,w_y2,w_y1 = i,(y-y1)/(y2-y1),(y2-y)/(y2-y1)
            break
    if xi is None or yi is None:
        return False 
        # You could add special cases to interpolate past the range if you would like. 
    # Find the weighted average between the four corners. 
    ave  = grid[yi][xi]    *w_y1*w_x1
    ave += grid[yi][xi+1]  *w_y1*w_x2
    ave += grid[yi+1][xi]  *w_y2*w_x1
    ave += grid[yi+1][xi+1]*w_y2*w_x2
    return ave

print(f(0,0),f(2.5,0),f(4,0),f(5,0),f(7.5,0),f(10,0))
print(f(0,1),f(2.5,1),f(4,1),f(5,1),f(7.5,1),f(10,1))
print(f(0,2),f(2.5,2),f(4,2),f(5,2),f(7.5,2),f(10,2))
```

This could be done more efficiently with more information. For example, if you had consistent x_delta between your x values, you could skip the for loops. You could also skip the for loops if you use a SortedList from the sortedcontainers package. This could probably also be adapted for numpy if you wanted to use arrays instead of lists, etc.

You didn't provide me any working code or knowledge about modules you can use or algorithm you wanted, so I wrote this up without as best I could. :-)

---

Edit:

You shouldn't make people type out your data from a PNG image. Here is a small section, I can't type out more.

```
X    = [0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2] 
Y    = [0.2,0.4] 
grid = [[1,1.116,1.211,1.297,1.376],[1,1.094,1.174,1.248,1.319]]

...

print(f(0,0.2),f(0.025,0.2),f(0.05,0.2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! I was not sure about the interpolation type, maybe linear will do, I edited the question and added some more details. I plotted the rows to show the numbers trend

Comment: Ya, I am sure that scipy is going to do some kind of complicated smoothing over the region. More importantly, those smoothing regions don't look independent (i.e., only depend on their respective corners, but take into consideration the whole graph). If you want that kind of complicated algorithm, you need to just copy and paste the scipy source code.

Comment: yes, that's true, the interp2d code is so long really. just one thing, I did not grasp your example. since I have to give 2 values, one for the top row and one for the first bolded column, and then my code should find its adjacent columns,shall you explain it on my chosen numbers so I can understand ?

Comment: I did not understand how you represented my table with X, Y and Grid

Comment: I added an example from your PNG image.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I did not mean it. if I just know how I could paste it in a good format, I would do it

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help !

Comment: No problem. It's fine. Glad I could help.

Comment: It really did. just one thing, if by any chance you could tell me what does the enumerate zip does, and in case I wanted to change the method to polynomial, which parts should I change ?

Comment: ah ! and one thing, if I read my table from excel, is there a way to put them programmatically in the order "grid" array has ?

Comment: What module are you using to read your CSV file. Are you using pandas, csv? This will certainly be a manual process using some zips and such.

Comment: I'm doing
 workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)----
inputdata=workbook.Worksheets("Values").Select()-----    
ws1 = workbook.Worksheets("Values")

Comment: then I can access each  cell with ws1.Cells(2,1).Value2 and so on

Comment: I have not used excel.Workbooks before. It sounds like you need to do some for loops to get your lists of data. Maybe there is a .to_list() attribute? You should probably ask this as a separate question if you get stuck.